# Integrate $s(x)= e^{-0.014x^{0.88}}$

Tags: integration

I have a survival function $s(x)= e^{-0.014x^{0.88}}$

Now, I wanna find the surface under this curve at $x=1015$. However, I get stuck as I get a negative outcome. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: "at x=1015" the curve has no surface area. It just has a height. Do you, perhaps, mean "between $x = 0$ and $x = 1015$"?

Comment: What's a survival function?

Comment: numerical methods, integrating a Taylor Series with -0.014x^0.88 substituted into it perhaps

Comment: I indeed mean between x=0 and x-1015. I need the definite integral then, right? A survival function is used to determine what proportion of a population is still alive at a certain time.

Comment: @Talitha01 `However, I get stuck as I get a negative outcome` Could you share your steps and show where you are stuck?

Comment: What I have done is integrate u=-0.014x^0.88 -> -0.014 * 0.53x^1.88 = -0.007x^1.88 
And then divide e^-0.014x^0.88/-0.0007x^1.88, which leads to negative outcome for any positive value you fill in x. I am not sure however if I did it correctly, since I haven't done much mathematics the past years.

Comment: The derivative of $e^u$ is $u' e^u$, but $(e^u/U)$ is not an antiderivative of $e^u$ (here, $U$ is an antiderivative of $u$). Indeed, if you differentiate $(e^u/U)$, you get $(u'e^u/U-e^u/U^2)$, which is quite different.

Comment: integrating e^(x^.88) isn't as easy as that I'm afraid, that sort of u sub fails to work that well - for example $e^{x^2}$ is a famous integral requiring special functions

Comment: Thanks guys! I see now.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your integral as 
\begin{equation}
 {\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{7x^\frac{22}{25}}{500}}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
Take the following change of variable 
\begin{equation}
 u=\dfrac{7^\frac{25}{22}x}{2^\frac{25}{11}{\cdot}125^\frac{25}{22}}
\end{equation}
which means that $\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{2^\frac{25}{11}{\cdot}125^\frac{25}{22}}{7^\frac{25}{22}}\,\mathrm{d}u$. You get
\begin{equation}
 {\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{7x^\frac{22}{25}}{500}}\,\mathrm{d}x
 ={{\dfrac{2^\frac{25}{11}{\cdot}125^\frac{25}{22}}{7^\frac{25}{22}}}}{\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{-u^\frac{22}{25}}\,\mathrm{d}u
\end{equation}
The integral ${\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{-u^\frac{22}{25}}\,\mathrm{d}u$ is known as the [Incomplete Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), i.e.
\begin{equation}
 {\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{-u^\frac{22}{25}}\,\mathrm{d}u
=-\dfrac{25\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{25}{22},u^\frac{22}{25}\right)}{22}
\end{equation}
Replacing and undoing the change of variable, we get
\begin{equation}
 {\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{7x^\frac{22}{25}}{500}}\,\mathrm{d}x
 =-\dfrac{25{\cdot}2^\frac{14}{11}{\cdot}125^\frac{25}{22}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{25}{22},\frac{7x^\frac{22}{25}}{500}\right)\sqrt[25]{x}}{11{\cdot}7^\frac{25}{22}\left|\sqrt[25]{x}\right|}+C
\end{equation}